# function does not execute when button is pressed a second time

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the function I'm using.

```
function beHonest() {
    if (document.getElementById("about").style.opacity = "0") {
        document.getElementById("about").style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("about").style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
```

When I press the button, it calls the function. When I press the button a second time, the else statement does not seem to execute. Why is this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `==` in the `if` condition of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is currently written like an assignation:

```
if (document.getElementById("about").style.opacity = "0")
```

You must write:

```
if (document.getElementById("about").style.opacity == "0")
```

Comment: @user5684138. The assignation does _not_ produce the same effect! I guess you mean "why does it work 1st time?". In fact, it _does_ work each time, but every time the same  way, so you don't see any difference.

Comment: I came to that conclusion as I wrote my comment on your answer! Thanks. :)

Comment: @user5684138. Glad to help. So might you consider to accept my answer. TIA.

Comment: @user5684138. Now for me just like previously for you: I saw it was done just when I posted my comment :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well ==

> if (document.getElementById("about").style.opacity == "0") {

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value to 0 and checking the object. It is true so you enter on closure and set to 1